# cant find SpringBeans.groovy in resources folder but i can find log4j.properties - any idea why it wont find file?

Tags: spring, groovy, resources, classpath

i have a simple spring file with some sample code in it

```
static main(args) {
    // Load the spring beans
    BeanBuilder beanBuilder = new BeanBuilder()
    //beanBuilder.loadBeans("classpath:SpringBeans.groovy")
    beanBuilder.loadBeans("file:src/main/resources/SpringBeans.groovy")
def res = new ClassPathResource ("log4j.properties")
    File fprop = res.getFile()
    assert fprop.exists()
```

for the beanBuilder.loadBeans i have had to use a fixed absolute file URI.  I have tried to read the log4j.properties in the same folder and that works using ClassPathResource - and the assert is fine

but if i try this looking for the SpringBeans.groovy file

```
def res = new ClassPathResource ("SpringBeans.groovy")  
File fprop = res.getFile()
assert fprop.exists()
```

also in the root of the resources folder - the assertion fails.

to get the loadBeans to work i have to put in an absolute file: URI and i want to use classpath form - but this fails to find it.

why can i see the log4j.properties but not the SpringBeans.groovy file ?

Any help gratefully received

i've added following into my gradle build file to ensure i'm getting the resources directory.  And eclipse shows the resources directory is included also `enter code here`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src/main/groovy'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Eclipse will treat the *log4j.properties* file as a resource and simply copy it to the output folder, *SpringBeans.groovy* will be compiled and you should find *SpringBeans.class* in the output folder instead of the .groovy file.
Eclipse allows you to define Groovy script folders. Groovy files matching the defined patterns will not be compiled and copied to the output folder.
To configure Groovy script folders go to **Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler** and check "Enable script folder support". You can also define a project specific behavior from the project properties.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you - i'd seen that section and not really recognised what it did so have always left it untouched.  Enabled it and left the check mark on the *.groovy and then rebuild.  and lo and be hold the script gets put into the output bin directory thanks ever so much